# Looping for only certain objects

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm writing a program that's supposed to rank and sort contenders in a competition.

```
# Defining class. Also sorts the array elements in ascending order.
class Dancer
attr_reader :couplenumber
attr_reader :scores
def initialize(couplenumber,scores)
@couplenumber=couplenumber
@scores=scores.sort
end 
end

# Opening file, and sorting into array. Also splits with ",".
results = File.open("danceresult.txt", "r+")
dancescores=[]
results.each do |result|
scores = result.split(',').map(&:to_i) 
couplenumber = scores.shift
dancescores << Dancer.new(couplenumber, scores)
end
dancescores.each do |dancers|
  dancers.scores
  # Prints to screen.
  puts "Couple No. #{dancers.couplenumber} got "\
       "a minimum score of #{dancers.scores[3]} or better. "\
       "Their sum is: #{dancers.scores[0..3].inject(:+)}"
end
```

I want the sum `Their sum is: #{dancers.scores[0..3].inject(:+)}` to take only those who have the lowest minimum score. So if we have five contenders, two of them get minimum score of 2, and the other three gets a minimum score of 4, then the "sum part" should only take the contenders with a minimum score of 2. Is it possible without having to rework all of the code, and if so, what is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't have shown all this code. Instead, show an example of the array, and the result you want.

Comment: @sawa: I beg to differ. Context can be important, and it's not always a priori clear whether it will be.

Comment: A better explanation of the desired output would be nice, but not showing code results in comments of "What have you tried?" (and rightly so)

Comment: I tried to shorten down the code.

Comment: Basically it loads a set of scores in from a file. I want the 4th element (score) in the array to be compared for each one. Meaning if one array has a 2 at the 4th position, and another array has a 2 at the 4th position, then i want them to calculate the sum. The way its going right now it calculates the sum wether or not they have the same score(element) on the 4th position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First establish what the minimum score is:

```
min_score = dancescores.map{|d| d.scores[3]}.min
```

Then add a conditional before your print:

```
dancescores.each do |dancer|
  # Prints to screen if the couple has the min_score
  if dancer.scores[3] == min_score
    puts "Couple No. #{dancer.couplenumber} got "\
       "a minimum score of #{dancer.scores[3]} or better. "\
       "Their sum is: #{dancer.scores[0..3].inject(:+)}"
  end
end
```

Or you can use `select` to handle only those dancers with the min_score like so:

```
dancescores.select{|d| d[3] == min_score}.each do |dancer|
  puts "Couple No. #{dancer.couplenumber} got "\
     "a minimum score of #{dancer.scores[3]} or better. "\
     "Their sum is: #{dancer.scores[0..3].inject(:+)}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, thats excactly something like that i had in mind. However, im getting `undefined local variable or method 'all_dancers' for main:Object (NameError)` - when parsing this code directly. Do i need to change all_dancers into the name of the array with all the scores, or how?

Comment: When you edited your question, you replaced `dancescores` which was an array of `Dancer` objects with `arr1` which is just an array of scores.  This no longer makes sense since a score does not have a `couplenumber` nor an array of `scores` associated with it. I was addressing your direct question of how to select just the dancers with the lowest score.  Go back to your previous version of your code where you created the `dancerscores` array.  I will change `all_dancers` to match your original question.